# AJAX causing a page to become unresponsive

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have the following code running in a game kind of thing on my website.

```
function checkGameState(n) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "gamestate.php?c="+player_correct+"&i="+player_incorrect+"&id="+n,
        context: document.body
    }).done(function( data ) {
        checkGameState(n)
        if (getCookie("gid")!=false) {
            obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            player = getCookie('player');
            if (player=='1') {
                if ((opponent_correct<=parseFloat(obj.player2c)) && (opponent_incorrect<=parseFloat(obj.player2i))) {
                    opponent_correct = parseFloat(obj.player2c);
                    opponent_incorrect = parseFloat(obj.player2i);
                }
            } else {
                if ((opponent_correct<=parseFloat(obj.player1c)) && (opponent_incorrect<=parseFloat(obj.player1i))) {
                    opponent_correct = parseFloat(obj.player1c);
                    opponent_incorrect = parseFloat(obj.player1i);
                }
            }
            renderBars();
        }
    });
}
```

The function `checkGameState` is called when the game starts and as you can see recursively calls after that.  There is also a single player version of this game which obviously doesn't use this code.  The problem is that seemingly randomly chrome becomes unresponsive while playing the multiplayer version of this game.  The only thing that is different is the above AJAX code.

Does anyone know how to stop this error from occurring?

**UPDATE `renderBars()` as requested**

```
function renderBars() {
    //players calculations
    c = player_correct;
    i = player_incorrect;
    s = player_startTime;
    $correct = $(".score-correct");
    $incorrect = $(".score-incorrect");
    t=c+i;
    t=(t==0)?1:t;
    x=5;
    h=0
    if (get_cookie("high"+getLevel())) {
        h=parseFloat(get_cookie("high"+getLevel()));
        $(".levitate .row h5").last().text(h);
        h+=i;
        h=Math.round(h/2);
    }
    while (x<t || x<h) {
        x+=5;
    }
    $(".levitate .row h5").first().text((c*2)-i); 
    //players high score bar calculations
    if (h || h==0) {
        if (h<=x) {
            if (c<h) {
                $(".score-high").css("opacity","1").css("height",(Math.round((h/x)*100*0.9))+"%");
                $(".score-high b").html("<b style='position:relative;top:-40px'>"+h+"</b>")
            } else {
                $(".score-high").css("opacity","0");
            }
        }
    }
    //opponent calculations
    var ox=0;
    if (typeof opponent_correct !== 'undefined') {
        c = opponent_correct;
        i = opponent_incorrect;
        s = player_startTime;
        $ocorrect = $(".score-correct").last();
        $oincorrect = $(".score-incorrect").last();
        t=c+i;
        t=(t==0)?1:t;
        ox=5;
        while (x<t) {
            ox+=5;
        }
    }
    //determine which scale to use
    if (x<=ox) {
        x=ox;
    }
    //change heights of the score bars
    $incorrect.css("height",((Math.round((player_incorrect/(x))*100))*0.9)+"%");
    $correct.css("height",((Math.round((player_correct/(x))*100))*0.9)+"%");
    if (($correct.parent().height()*(((Math.round((player_correct/(x))*100))*0.9)/100))>25) {
        $correct.html("<b>"+player_correct+"</b>")
    } else {
        $correct.html("<b style='position:relative; top:-28px'>"+player_correct+"</b>")
    }
    if (($incorrect.parent().height()*(((Math.round((player_incorrect/(x))*100))*0.9)/100))>25) {
        $incorrect.html("<b>"+player_incorrect+"</b>")
    } else {
        $incorrect.html("<b style='position:relative; top:-28px'>"+player_incorrect+"</b>")
    }
    if (typeof opponent_correct !== 'undefined') {
        $oincorrect.css("height",((Math.round((opponent_incorrect/(x))*100))*0.9)+"%");
        $ocorrect.css("height",((Math.round((opponent_correct/(x))*100))*0.9)+"%");
        if (($ocorrect.parent().height()*(((Math.round((opponent_correct/(x))*100))*0.9)/100))>25) {
            $ocorrect.html("<b>"+opponent_correct+"</b>")
        } else {
            $ocorrect.html("<b style='position:relative; top:-28px'>"+opponent_correct+"</b>")
        }
        if (($oincorrect.parent().height()*(((Math.round((opponent_incorrect/(x))*100))*0.9)/100))>25) {
            $oincorrect.html("<b>"+opponent_incorrect+"</b>")
        } else {
            $oincorrect.html("<b style='position:relative; top:-28px'>"+opponent_incorrect+"</b>")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're infinitely calling `checkGameState(n)`.  It makes an ajax call and as soon as it receives the response immediately makes another ajax call, indefinitely.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes, the idea is that it is constantly fetching the opponents "state" (scores and such)

Comment: What error? If you get an error, paste it here. And what are the `getCookie` and `renderBars` methods doing? Maybe they block the ui? Try debugging using chrome's "Timeline", to see which method is blocking the UI.

Comment: `getCookie` is a standard function to retreive a cookie value.  `renderBars` is a function that takes the scores that were just updated and changes the height of some score bars on the page.  The error is the "A page has become unresponsive" error in chrome, where the entire page stops working and a box comes up asking you to "kill the page" or "wait".

Comment: You may need to think about throttling the calls to `checkGameState`. The least you could probably do is move the recursive call to the end of your `done` callback so if something in your callback is stalled, it won't keep firing off more and more calls.

Comment: Do the values returned by `getCookie` actually change? Maybe then can be cached? You could also eliminate the repeated calls to `parseFloat` with the same value. But in all likelihood, I would suspect the problem is in `renderBars`. What does that look like?

Comment: I'll update the question with `renderBars` and I know it isn't pretty I'll get around to cleaning it up eventually.  Just trying to get the principle functions working for know :D

Comment: If your state doesn't change all the time, you might think about using push notifications using [WebSockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) in HTML5 instead of this constant polling. I'm sure you could search for a framework that would work for you.

Comment: checkGameState() is asynchronous, and it sets values to global variables `obj` and `player`. At some point your program can enter first `if` (for `player==1`) and the value of obj can change at that point, breaking your logic. I don't think that can cause browser unresponsiveness, but there are too many things that can go wrong with your code...

Comment: You should probably rethink the design. At the very least, don't call `checkGameState` again until you've finished processing the previous request. There's just too much that'll go wrong if another request comes back before the previous one has finished processing (I'm guessing you are running locally, so that's a big potential problem). I would look at various push techniques (like WebSockets) so that updates will only run when there is actually something to update. You should only trigger `renderBars` if they actually need to be updated.

Comment: There's a mess of implicit global variables in `renderBars()`.  That's a very bad practice.  Don't know if it is a culprit here, but it can easily cause problems.  Delcare all your local variables using `var`.

Comment: I took a serious look at web sockets but my problem is that my hosting is "shared hosting" and I haven't found a web socket framework that works on shared hosting.  If someone can point me in the right direction I would happily mark that as the answer :D